# Laravel Decimal price field always dirty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

i am have decimal(10,2) column in MySQL for store product price.

Eloquent fetch it and we have: `$product->getOriginal('price') // string(6) "985.00"`

Then i set `$product->price = (float)985` and `$product->getDirty('price')` returns that `price` field is dirty.
And then eloquent make update query if i `$product->save()`, but value is same, and not need to be updated.

I dont want to make `UPDATE` query each time to set same values, i want only `UPDATE` queries when price is really changes

i make this code

```
public function setPriceAttribute($val)
{
    $this->attributes['price'] = sprintf('%.2f', $val);
}
```

and `$casts = ['price' => 'float']`
It work for me, but i am think thats not good practice

Comment: What bothers you about the `$casts` array?

Comment: my question is "i am really must to create for each decimal mysql column an Eloquent Model mutator (in this case `setPriceAttribute` or there is more nice solution?"

Comment: My suggestion is: put any effort that is necessary in the model. To answer your question 'i am really must to create for each...' the answer is yes. The more your models suit your needs, the less effort you need for the controllers and especially, the views.